# Does every paper in mathematics have Zbl and MR?

Tags: publications, citations, paper-submission, review-databases

I need to insert the Zbl and MR of papers given in the reference of my paper. I can't find Zbl of some the papers. for example the paper [On Inverse Eigenvalue Problems for Two Kinds of Special Banded Matrices](http://journal.pmf.ni.ac.rs/filomat/index.php/filomat/article/view/2064). I search in the `https://zbmath.org/` database to find Zbl but it returns no result, I also search in`https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup` to find the MR.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to add these if you can't find them? Is there some journal that requires references to include them?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes the journal asks to include them

Comment: I see. That is very surprising, as I have never encountered a journal that requires those to be included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your paper is [MR 3628846](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3628846).

MR and Zbmath don't index ***every*** paper in mathematics.  Each one has a list of specific journals that they index; these lists are extensive but not exhaustive.  New journals are sometimes added, and journals can be dropped if they cease publishing regularly or don't keep their quality up.  However, MathSciNet at least does index the journal where your paper appeared (I didn't check Zbmath).

Both services operate mainly by subscription (usually institutional subscriptions).  As you've found, they do offer limited searching to non-subscribers (e.g. the MR Lookup service) but it is, well, limited, and it is not unusual to have trouble finding a paper through the free searches.  The full subscription version offers much more powerful searching.  In this case, however, when I pasted the paper's title into the "title" field of MR Lookup, it returned the paper right away, so I am not sure why you were having trouble.

Comment: The MR is ok, but can't find Zbl

Comment: I suspect Zbmath ceased indexing that journal in 2016. Plenty of results from 2016 and before, but none from 2017 or later.

Comment: Update: starting from 2021, Zbmath offers unlimited functionalities to non-subscribers.